# Selenium or Any other best UI test automation framework with very less maintenance suggestions?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

*Dear Experts,*

Suggest me a best test automation framework with less maintenance work.

**Problem Statement:**

Currently im using test automation framework built by Selenium
Whenever there is a changes in the DOM(Document Object Model) - the element identification fails.
here comes the maintenance activity(complex) for failing scripts.

I'm not familiar on latest trends.

Need suggestions \ guidance on the latest or Best UI Automation framework with very little maintenance activity.

Also happy to know your preference and reason too

Appreciate your suggestion and directions

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Go check Katalon test automation tool it is based on selenium framework with many enhance functionalities on API testing,Mobile testing. Chexk this link -->https://www.katalon.com

Comment: Thank you for showing a direction. are you using that tool ?

Comment: Yes i have used that tool and i felt it is way more easy to use and challenges which i faced in selenium will be handled easily using Katalon.

Comment: sounds great. did katalon supports BDD - Cocumber ? it seems the tool supports only groovy and java.

Comment: Katalon Studio 5.7 introduces all-new BDD testing capability allowing Business stakeholders to get involved in the testing process